# How to avoid valgrind strlen error?

Tags: linux, valgrind

I run at first time valgerind on code.

I got the next error:

```
valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:  
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux.so.2
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux.so.2
```

what can i do to solve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in Valgrind: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=286864
A [patch](http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=82043) for it is available for Debian, but it doesn't look like a complete solution:

However, performing a `sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg:i386` seems to have solved it for [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/280757/148011) person.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but I didn't succeed to install it.(ubuntu).

Comment: Hope one of these would solve it: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=libc6-dbg&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=sOHRU9OBDurV8gfYpoCYBg